Mocking a nested function call with pytest
If I have a function, A1, that is being tested, and that function imports and calls function B1, which itself calls B2 from the same file, how do I mock function B2?
If I mock with mocker.patch('B.B2', return_value=return_value), the mocked function doesn't get called.  If I mock with 'A.B2', 'A.B1.B2', 'A.B.B2', or anything like that, I get errors because those don't exist.  I understand if I wanted to mock B1 in this situation, I would mock 'A.B1' because of how it's being imported and where it's being used, but I can't find a way to mock B2 which is being called inside B1.
File layout is as follows, to give a visual.
File B
def B2():
    # does a thing, should be mocked

def B1():
    B2()

File A
from B import B1

def A1():
    B1()

Test File
def test_a1():
    from A import A1
    A1()


"If I mock with mocker.patch('B.B2', return_value=return_value), the mocked function doesn't get called." It is unclear why this is not what you want, since B2 "does a thing, should be mocked", and patching B.B2 does avoid B2 being called.

Sorry, let me rephrase.  The mocked version of the function doesn't get called, the original unmocked function does.

Nevermind, the mocked version was getting called, there was something else overwriting the output of the mocked function.  With that fixed, the test passes.  Thank you for commenting.

It might not be obvious but you should patch functions based on where there were used and not where they were defined.
So in your case you could achieve it by following way:
from A import A1
from unittest import mock

def test_a1():
    with mock.patch('B.B2', return_value="some random val") as mock_b2:
        A1()
        mock_b2​


I explicitly called this out in the question as not working in this manner

This did turn out to be the correct answer.  There was something else in the code overwriting the output of that function.  Thank you for your patience.
